# How can I make the "non-custom Windows 10 title bar" of Google Chrome respect the Windows theme switch

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, windows-11

How can I make the non-native Windows 10 title bar of Google Chrome respect the Windows theme switch and change to the theme I choose, depending on the system OS theme?

1. I enable the non-native title bar on Google Chrome by adding the argument  --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar to the Google Chrome shortcut
2. System and app switches to a dark theme
3. The theme color does not switch on Google Chrome when Windows 10 custom title bar is disabled.

Expected behavior (by changing chrome's theme color to dark):
[image: Dark Tabs on dark theme]

Actual behavior (by changing chrome's theme color to default):
[image: White Tabs on dark theme]

Comment: [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/blw2d6/custom_drawn_windows_10_titlebar_option_gone/) suggests to set the `chrome.exe` *Properties > Compatibility* to Windows 7 and try adding `--disable-windows10-custom-titlebar `.

Comment: OK thanks changing compatibility worked.

Comment: Since it worked for you. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the post
[Custom drawn windows 10 titlebar option gone](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/blw2d6/custom_drawn_windows_10_titlebar_option_gone/)
a user solved the problem by right-click on `chrome.exe` and setting
*Properties > Compatibility* to Windows 7 and then adding the parameter
`--disable-windows10-custom-titlebar`, like this :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar
```